# Не видит атрибут таблицы в триггере

Tags: sql, oracle

Создаю триггер `BEFORE DELETE` для таблицы `Clients`, чтобы предотвратить удаление связанных данных в других таблицах. В нём пытаюсь обратиться к `:old.client_id`, однако Oracle SQL Developer показывает ошибку: 
`Error(8,6): PLS-00201: identifier 'CLIENT_ID' must be declared`.

Поле `client_id` действительно существует, запрос `SELECT client_id FROM Clients` выполняется верно, права у пользователя есть. Ума не приложу, что делать... Код триггера следующий:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CL_DENY_DELETING
BEFORE DELETE ON Clients
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  OLD_CL_ID NUMBER;
  CL_ID NUMBER;
BEGIN
  OLD_CL_ID := :OLD.CLIENT_ID;

  SELECT CLIENT_ID INTO CL_ID 
  FROM CLIENTS_HAS_ISSUE WHERE
  CLIENTS_HAS_ISSUE.CLIENT_ID = OLD_CL_ID; 

  IF CLIENT_ID = OLD_CL_ID
  THEN
    RAISEERROR('Эта информация не может быть удалена!');
    ROLLBACK WORK;
END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. У вас ошибка в строке `IF CLIENT_ID = OLD_CL_ID` - никакой переменной CLIENT_ID у вас не объявлено. Видимо стоило написать `IF CL_ID=OLD_CL_ID`
2. Если в таблице CLIENTS_HAS_ISSUE окажется более одной записи с требуемым CLIENT_ID то у вас будет ошибка выполнения. Триггер стоило бы записать в виде:

   ```
   CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CL_DENY_DELETING
   BEFORE DELETE ON Clients
   FOR EACH ROW
   DECLARE
     CNT NUMBER;
   BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(1) INTO CNT
      FROM CLIENTS_HAS_ISSUE
     WHERE CLIENT_ID = :OLD.CLIENT_ID;

    IF CNT>0 THEN
      RAISEERROR('Эта информация не может быть удалена!');
    END IF;
   END;
   ```
3. ROLLBACK в триггере не нужен, ибо ошибка сгенерированная RAISE автоматически приведет к откату транзакции.
4. Если красивые сообщения об ошибках создавать в пользовательском приложении, то вместо триггера было бы проще (и более правильно с точки зрения БД) создать внешний ключ:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE CLIENTS_HAS_ISSUE
     ADD CONSTRAINT fk_CLIENTS_HAS_ISSUE
         FOREIGN KEY (CLIENT_ID) REFERENCES Clients(CLIENT_ID);
   ```

Answer (score 1):

У Вас ругается не на поле в таблице, а на строку `IF CLIENT_ID = OLD_CL_ID`.
Переменная `CLIENT_ID` не определена в тригере.
Судя по коду в этом месте `CLIENT_ID` следует заменить на `CL_ID`.